# How can I re-add a friends posts to my newsfeed?

Tags: facebook

A while ago I removed one of my friend's posts from my Facebook news feed. I'd like to add them back to the feed, but can't find any way of doing this. I suppose I could un-friend & re-friend them but that seems like overkill and is likely to wipe all of our wall-to-wall info.

Answer (score 3):

**Home** => **News Feed (Most Recent)** => Scroll to the bottom of the page and click **Edit Options** => Under the **Hide** remove the blocked friend

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays (2018), there are two options to stop seeing posts from someone, and they can be canceled from the same location: unfollow and snooze.

### Remove friend's posts

- Unfollow

  > **Unfollow Bob**
  >   <sub>Stop seeing posts but stay friends</sub>
- Snooze

  > **Snooze Bob for 30 days**
  >   <sub>Temporarily stop seeing posts</sub>

Those can be chosen from the three dots menu [image] at the top left (or right, if using an RTL language) of each post:

[image]

- Note that both actions can be undo immediately after applied, from the news feed, at the exact location it was done (assuming you stayed there).

### Bring back this friend's posts

1. Open your friend's profile
2. On the cover photo, there are three buttons, the middle one is for following settings.

   - The default:

     [image]
   - See first:

     [image]
   - If you unfollowed and want to re-follow:

     [image]
   - If you snoozed and want to end it:

     [image]

### Blocking

If you blocked a friend, which is something else (although you also won't see their posts), you can unblock them from the [**Blocking** tab on Facebook settings](https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=blocking)

### More details from Facebook Help pages

- [How do I follow or unfollow a profile or Page?](https://www.facebook.com/help/276458109035418)
- [What does it mean to unfollow someone?](https://www.facebook.com/help/190078864497547)
- [How do I snooze a person, Page or group?](https://www.facebook.com/help/538433456491590)

A little while after you first unfollow someone, Facebook will show you this on your feed, to let you understand better what it means:

[image]

The learn more about unfollowing redirects to [here](https://www.facebook.com/help/190078864497547)

Answer (score 0):

From your home page:

- Hover over the News Feed bookmark in the left column
- Click the  icon that appears to the left and select Edit Settings
- Click X next to the name of the friend, Page, group, event or app whose stories you want to unhide
- Click Save