# Stop receiving notification of a friend

Tags: facebook

I don't want to see the updates of a person who is in my friend list on my wall. Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: Do you mean in your news feed or do you not want them to be able to post on your wall?

Comment: Related: [How to re-add a friend's posts to my newsfeed?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/9824/how-can-i-re-add-a-friends-posts-to-my-newsfeed) <-- the answer to this one works in either direction

Answer (score 1):

Go to your friend's list, search your friend, and click on his profile. Then click to manage list and unmark notification.